# 3d straightedge and compass

Tags: 3d, spheres, geometric-construction

Given a tool that can draw a sphere by given center and a point on it and a surface by given 3 points, is the constructable set of the tool equivalent to the streightedge and compass constructable numbers? In simpler words, is there anything you can construct in 3d and not in 2d? And why?

Comment: Nice question. Have you any ideas on how to answer it?

Comment: Well... Thinking of it intersecting things would never lead to some new length ratio, but there is more to do with 3d. For instance, in 2d it is not possible to trisect an angle since the ratio of lengths is unconstructable. But in 3d you have more freedom since you have 2 axis of angles. So if this would be the case, the ratio of lengths in the trisection would become constructable in 3d. Another thing is, though I didn't find a way to make unconstructable numbers constructable, I found a way to make something more easily constructable. It is easier to construct a conic's foci in 3d than in 2

Comment: You can construct 3 perpendicular lines in 3D, but not in 2D?

Comment: Trisection effectively requires the solution of a corresponding cubic equation, but intersections between lines, planes, cylinders, and spheres all yield solutions to quadratic equations

Comment: Euclid Books 11, 12, and 13 are all in three dimensions.